# docker image error downloading package

Tags: docker, centos, pip

I am trying to build a docker image (using my Dockerfile) and I get a very strange error about insufficient space in the download directory:

```
Total download size: 208 k
Installed size: 760 k
Downloading packages:

Error downloading packages:
  libyaml-0.1.4-11.el7_0.x86_64: Insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/centos/packages
    * free   0 
    * needed 55 k
  PyYAML-3.10-11.el7.x86_64: Insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/centos/packages
    * free   0 
    * needed 153 k

The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y install python-yaml' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I am using a centos7 base image

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  106M  1.5G   7% /run
/dev/sda1       118G  112G     0 100% /
tmpfs           7.9G  648K  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1        92G  206M   87G   1% /boot
tmpfs           1.6G   56K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1001
```

Comment: Check and make sure `/var` has sufficient space as this is the place where `docker` would store its images. To do so: `df -h /var`

Comment: $ sudo du -sh /var/cache/
573M /var/cache/ AND 958M    /var/

Comment: As mentioned, it is 100% full thus the insufficent space error. I have listed 2 possibilities on how you can free up some space. refer to the solution

Answer (score 44):

The following `docker` command was the trick to fix the underlying error for me:

`$ docker rm $(docker ps -qa)`

Comment: perfect answer, Thanks!

Comment: Nice hack :) 
It also helps when building a new docker image.
It would be interesting to know how to diagnose the problem and why removing old containers help

Comment: This by far should be at the top

Comment: In my case it does not work. I says 'docker rm requires at least 1 argument'

Comment: @Berni sounds like in your environment `$(docker ps -qa)` is giving an empty output to `docker rm ...`. Perhaps you no longer have any dangling containers that can be removed by `docker rm`.

Answer (score 17):

For me, running:

```
docker image prune
```

did the trick. It turned out I had lots of garbage (a.k.a., *dangling*) images taking up space. `prune` docs can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/).

Comment: worked like charm!

Answer (score 6):

Check and make sure the /var directory has sufficient space as that is where `docker` stores its images.

To do so: `df -h /var`

If it is 100% full you might want to clear up some space.

`docker ps -a` - to list all of the containers (including those stopped and exited ones). use `docker rm {CONTAINER_ID}` to free up some space.

Alternatively do `docker images` to remove unused images. `docker rmi {IMAGE_ID}`.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to check where the space was used at first.

```
du -h /var | grep -E ‘^[0-9.]*[M|G]’
```

If any specific directory is used too much spaces, you check how to remove it properly. And you do it.

You ever have not removed docker containers or images?
It usually is high possibility for root cause of the unsufficient space issues.

Check it by following command.

```
du -hs /var/lib/docker
```

If the directory has too much spaces, you would solve docker commands below.

Removing all containers,

```
docker rm $(docker ps -qa)
```

Removing docker all images,

```
docker rmi $(docker image ls -qa)
```

But the cause may not be the docker around, such as big log files or rpm cache and some big files. And then you can remove the files.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

The following command works for me:

```
docker system prune
```

This will allow you to prune all the dangling images, dangling build caches, networks that are not in use.